# Get Tenant URL from Site collection in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, office-365, jsom

I have a site collection.
**https://rocket.sharepoint.com/sites/developing**

I have tenant : **https://rocket-admin.sharepoint.com**

Now i want to get tenant URL using java script object modal from the site collection URL which is mention above.

Is there any method in SP.Web object to fetch the information of respective tenant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

SP.Web doesn't contain admin URL (tenant URL), but you can do this with a simple JavaScript split method:

```
var str = "https://rocket.sharepoint.com/sites/developing";
var res = str.split(".sharepoint.com");
var adminUrl = res[0] + "-admin.sharepoint.com";
```